Closed expression of eigenfunctions of a two dimensional isotropic harmonic oscillator
Where can one find the closed expression of the eigenfunctions of the 2d isotropic harmonic oscillator?
I saw something like this:
$$ \psi_{n_r m }(r, \theta) \propto e^{im\theta} r^{|m|} e^{-r^2/2} F(-n_r, |m|+1, r^2) , $$
where $F$ is the confluent hypergeometric function. But what is the normalization factor?

See eqns. (2) and (3) in this paper.
